# JQuery display the result of $_POST loop over array and display on the screen, displays nothing

Tags: jquery

I would like to be able to display the results of my database query from JQuery. I supply my php script with two variables passed from $_POST using Jquery when an element is dropped.

```
drop: function(event, ui){
    var name = ui.draggable.find("img").attr("id");
    var path = ui.draggable.find("img").attr("alt");
    $.post('wardrobe.php', { name: name, path: path}, function(data){
        //append here!! 
    });     

}
```

A php array is passed back, (data), which contains six elements referenced by a key, for example

```
$result['name'] = $name;
```

I can display these elements great with PHP, however I would like JQuery to handle this as, I would like the results to be displayed in a modal.

I have tried the following to test, but nothing is displayed.

```
$.post('Create_Item_Controller.php', { name: name, path: path}, function(data){
                         $.each(data, function (i, elem) {

                            $('#display-inner').html(elem);

                         });
```

Also I have tried:

```
$('#display-inner').html(elem).show();
$('#display-inner').html(elem.title).show();
```

If I replace the array and just append (data) and echo some string from my php script, this displays correctly,

```
$('#display-inner').html(data); //displays the echo from php script correctly
```

so how do you list through  the array and display the contents of data referenced by it's key?
In addition, I would like to display each element within it's own div and append the div to #display-inner as shown in my code?

I have tried:

```
    content = “<div id=”item”<p><label>Title: </label> elem.name</p></div> “;
$(content).appendTo(#display-inner);
```

And now added JSON encode as suggested, however still nothing is displayed

```
        $.post('Create_Item_Controller.php', { name: name, path: path}, function(data){
                     $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
                     content = '<div id="item"<p><label>Title: </label> elem.name</p></div>';
                        $(content).appendTo('#display-inner');

                     });

            },'json');
```

I have made changes to both the JQuery and PHP scripts however still haveing the same problem

```
$.post('Create_Item_Controller.php', { name: name, path: path}, function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#display-inner').html(data.title);
                        $('#display-inner').html(data.name);
                        $('#display-inner').html(data.title);


            },"json");
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$js = new Create_Item_Controller();
$data = $js->getElement();
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I have also tried

```
echo json_encode( array( 'data' => $data ) );
```

I have now tried to change the code to use $.jsonGet

```
            var name = ui.draggable.find("img").attr("id");
            var path = ui.draggable.find("img").attr("alt");
            var url = 'Create_Item_Controller.php';
            $.getJSON(url, { name: name, path: path }, function(data){
                console.log(data);

                $('#display-inner').html(data.name);
                $('#display-inner').html(data);         
            });
```

PHP

```
$js = new Create_Item_Controller();
$data = $js->getElement();
echo json_encode($data);
```

Now get output from console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
(anonymous function)drag-drop.js:21
f.Callbacks.njquery-1.7.1.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery-1.7.1.js:2
wjquery-1.7.1.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d
```

Can anyone suggest how this could be done? Or where I am going wrong!

Thanks

Comment: Show us the response you are sending back. What format is it in ? Is it just straight up html ? Also what is `display-inner` is it just a div that's been converted into a dialog ?

Comment: Hi A php array is passed back to JQuery (data) $result['name'] = $name etc

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `dataType` parameter in you `$.post` call. As far as I remember, the default value is <strike>`text`</strike>(actually, it's intelligent guess) therefore receiving data will not be parsed as an `object` and you should not be able to iterate over its the elements/properties.

```
$.post('wardrobe.php', { name: name, path: path}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

#### Debugging server-side code:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $js = new Create_Item_Controller();
    $data = $js->getElement();

    die("DIE: " . print_r($data,1)); // see what is $data
    echo json_encode($data);

    // OR

    echo json_encode($data);
    die("JSON ERROR: " . json_last_error());
}
```

Official [json-last-error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) docs.

Either way you will get to conclusion which part of your code produces an error. Sadly, `json_encode` is known to return misformatted string or simply `NULL` when data contains `UTF-8` chars.

Comment: thanks jperovic however still nothing displayed, I am trying    $.post('Create_Item_Controller.php', { name: name, path: path}, function(data){
  $('#display-inner').html(data);
       
},'json');

Comment: is there a way to dump the contents of data in jquery?

Comment: try using `console.log(data)`. That will print nicely-formatted content into console....

Comment: my PHP script now looks like this: if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {

$js = new Create_Item_Controller();
$data = $js->getElement();
echo json_encode($data);

}

Comment: JQuery Json now looks like this: $.post('Create_Item_Controller.php', { name: name, path: path}, function(data){
 console.log(data);
 $('#display-inner').html(data.title);
        $('#display-inner').html(data.name);
},"json");  // Still no output ???

Comment: Hi Jperovic I have updated my original post still cannot get any output? Any suggestions? :(

Comment: when you do `$js->getElement()` what is the return type? An `array`? Or maybe some `object`? Bear in mind that `json_encode` cannot traverse `private` class members and you will get nothing...

Comment: public classes getElement() creates an item class which gets passed to an Item DOA which extracts all the details about the item, put it in an array and passes back to data, so should only be a basic array? I don't understand why I am not getting any result? I have updated my post to reflect the changes I have made, thanks for assistance on this jperovic, much appriciated

Comment: Hey Alan, I updated my answer as well to include how to debug server-side code. I suspect that data returned from request is invalid and that `jQuery` has nothing or little to do with this error.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jperovic, I have created an array and passed this back. $test['name'] = "test1";
$test['title'] = "test2"; 
  // see what is $data
echo json_encode($test); // in the console I now have objects!!!! so I think you my be right about the problem being server side, I don't understand how it works in php when I loop over the array? Can I pass two arguments from $.jsonGet to my php function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the array you are sending back in order to be able to iterate over it on the client side.

So here's what you would do in the php script.

```
echo json_encode( array( 'result' => $result ) );
```

Then on the client side.

```
$.post('wardrobe.php', { name: name, path: path}, function(data){
       $.each( data.result, function( i, element ){ 
           console.log( element ); // you can see this in the console. 
           // your code here
       });  
}, 'json');
```

Comment: I have added JSON encode as you suggested thanks, however nothing is displayed, I have placed additional code in my original post

Comment: open up your console, in your web developer tools.

Comment: within google chrome under console nothing is displayed when item is dropped??

Comment: I have changed my code to use $.jsonGet instead i now get a log in the console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
(anonymous function)drag-drop.js:21
f.Callbacks.njquery-1.7.1.js:2 I have updated my original post to reflect the changes
f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery-1.7.1.js:2
wjquery-1.7.1.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d